# MSBuild: Backward Relative Path in Include

Tags: msbuild

Forgive me if this is too simple - I'm almost completely new to MS Build. I have a project that is creating two different Silverlight solutions and the file hierarchy looks like this:

```
+ Project123
  + Assets
    + Images
    + Fonts
    + Video
  + Source
    + SL3
      - Project123-SL3.sln
      + Solution
        - App.xaml
        + Pages
    + SL4
      - Project123-SL4.sln
      + Solution
        - App.xaml
        + Pages
```

What I'd like to have happen is for MSBuild to reach above it's parent's (which is either `SL3` or `SL4`) parent (which is `Source`) and then into the sister folder of `Assets` to include this folder. I've been looking at *Specifying Inputs with Wildcards* on [How to: Use Wildcards to Build All Files in a Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171454(v=VS.90).aspx), but this doesn't really say how to walk up the relative tree and then back down again. Is this possible with MSBuild?

Comment: Hm ... Why not have your solutions include Assets, even if it sits up there? Projects can be shared amongst solutions, so why not abuse that :) ?

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: I only have one set of Assets. With videos, that folder could become quite large. Duplicating it under each solution would be a waste of space and money (this is on a cloud server that I pay for storage as well - like Azure).

Comment: virtual folders should alleviate the need to copy. Now, `MsBuild` should work on any MsBuild-based Visual Studio solution. Using latest and greatest (VS2010, .Net 4.0) is usually a good idea. Now, MsBuild is not the only tool which can build your solution on command line; devenv.exe can as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(VS.80).aspx In fact, msBuild and devenv.exe can produce different results, but when using devenv.exe on command line should compile the same as if you worked from GUI. Look up the virtual folders in VS2010, or whatever they are called.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: I'll look into virtual folders, thank you. I don't have a copy of VS on the server that will be building these, so devenv.exe wouldn't works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like that in your silverlight project file.

```
<Content Include="..\..\Assets\**\*"/>
```